# how to use a function as a argument of another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="button" id="one" value="1" OnClick='addValue("function(){document.getElementById("one")}")'>
```

I want to pass the id of this input as argument of addValue function. Where is the mistake here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things, use `this`

```
<input type="button" id="one" value="1" OnClick='addValue(this.id)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move the event listener out of the HTML and then you can access the value from the click events target.

```
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var value = evt.target.value;
    addValue(value);
});
```

Edit: or use @tymeJV's solution, though I'd recommend getting away from inline events.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use function as argument of another function then have a look at anonymous functions http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions, SetTimeout is a good example, you pass a function as an argument to it to call after specific time.

But I think you can accomplish this without passing function as argument as mentioned in the answer of @tymeJV.

Comment: is it possible to like in java just to put a function as an argument and in the moment of calling of the outer function, the inner function to be evaluated and their result taken like normal value by the outer function?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, but if you want the argument function to be able to access some identifiers that are accessible in the called function, then pass these values to it in the called function.

Comment: for example if the function "inner(6)" returns 1, I want to write outer(inner(6)) and this to have the same meaning like outer(1). I want to use just the result from the inner function, nothing else !!! How to achieve it ?